# LinkedList Printing in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I write the following codes to print the distance on textview

Firstly,

```
LinkedList<String> rawdistance = new LinkedList<String>();
LinkedList<Double> distance = new LinkedList<Double>();
```

Then, I initialize the two linked lists, both of them are correct, then when I run the following codes to convert string to double, the program can't work on my device, even if it does not have a error

```
for (int p=0; p<rawdistance.size(); p++) 
       {
           String tmp = rawdistance.get(p);
           if(tmp.equals(" within ten meter")) {distance.add(p,(double)7);}
           else if(tmp.equals(" within five meter")) {distance.add(p,(double) 3);}
           else if(tmp.equals(" within two meter")) {distance.add(p,(double) 1.5);}
           else if(tmp.equals(" within one meter")) {distance.add(p,(double) 0.5);}
           else 
           {distance.add(p,(double) 11);}

       }

.....


       for (int i=0; i<distance.size();i++)
       {

           textView33.append(distance.get(i) + " encounter");
       }
```

Then, I write the smiler code on J2SE

public class Friendrr {

```
public static void Main(String args[]){

    LinkedList<String> rawdistance = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<Double> distance = new LinkedList<Double>();

    rawdistance.add(0, " within ten meter");
    rawdistance.add(1, " within one meter");
    rawdistance.add(2, " within ten meter");
    rawdistance.add(3, " within two meter");



       for (int p=0; p<rawdistance.size(); p++) 
       {
           String tmp = rawdistance.get(p);
           if(tmp.equals(" within ten meter")) {distance.add(p,(double)7.0);}
           else if(tmp.equals(" within five meter")) {distance.add(p,(double)3.1);}
           else if(tmp.equals(" within two meter")) {distance.add(p,(double)1.5);}
           else if(tmp.equals(" within one meter")) {distance.add(p,(double)0.5);}
           else 
           {distance.add(p,(double)11);}

       }
       for(int i=0; i<rawdistance.size();i++){
       System.out.println(rawdistance.get(i));}
         System.out.println(distance);
    }

}
```

The output is  [[I@5e8fce95]

the output is strange ..

Comment: Be more specific. What do you mean by the program cannot work on my device? Is there anything in the log? What happens when you debug?

Comment: Please post the error that your getting, so that we would help you better!

Comment: Yes, I try the similar thing on J2SE, it seems the output has problem

Answer (score 0):

In your JSE code you wrote

```
System.out.println(distance);
```

'distance' is an object and '[[I@5e8fce95]' is the common string representation of an object without any toString method.